# Reading binary data from a file

Tags: python, performance

I have a binary file with alternating uint8 and uint64 data stamps.
I read those in by using the following line:

```
clicks = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=[('time','u8'),('channel','u2')])
```

This works well and fast enough. Now i want to go though the array and set the time values to the time difference with respect to the last 'click' seen on channel 7 (the so called gate clicks). The array is sorted by time. In C I would do this with a simple for loop going over the array (and this works extremly fast). When I implement this in python i get a data rate of only 2 mb/s. The best solution i came up with looks like this:

```
    ''' create an array with the indices of the channel-7 clicks '''
    gate_clicks = clicks['channel']==7
    gate_ind = np.array(range(len(gate_clicks)))
    gate_ind = gate_ind[gate_clicks]
    gate_ind_shift = np.delete(gate_ind,0,0)

    ''' slice out the clicks between to gate clicks and set the time stamps '''
    for start,end in zip(gate_ind,gate_ind_shift):
        start_time = data[start]['time']
        slice = data[start:end] 
        slice['time'] = slice['time']-start_time
        data[start:end] = slice
```

This gives a data rate of about 4.

Comment: Can you provide enough context so that we can run your code? That is, add `import` statements etc. so that the extract becomes a runnable problem, and provide us with example data to test it on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`numpy.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to group the data and vectorize the loop. Demo:

```
>>> clicks
array([(0L, 7), (1L, 0), (2L, 0), (3L, 0), (4L, 7), (5L, 0), (6L, 0),
       (7L, 0), (8L, 0), (9L, 7)],
      dtype=[('time', '<u8'), ('channel', '<u2')])
>>> bins = clicks['time'][clicks['channel']==7]
>>> bins
array([0, 4, 9], dtype=uint64)
>>> ind = np.digitize(clicks['time'], bins) - 1
>>> ind
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
>>> bins[ind]
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9], dtype=uint64)
>>> clicks['time'] - bins[ind]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0], dtype=uint64)
```